# Develop for Windows Phone 7 (or 7.1) using Visual Studio 2012 (RTM,Premium)

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone

Is it possible to get the WindowsPhone 7.1.1 sdk to work with Visual Studio 2012?

Edit: As stated in the title of my question: I wanted to know whether its possible to develop windows phone 7.1.1 apps using Visual Studio 2012.

I already tried installing the SDK and the hotfix but I still can't open Windows Phone 7.1 projects with VS2012. Hence, my question: Am I missing something obvious or is it simply not possbile?

Comment: Well, my comment was to the poorly researched and sparse question prior to the edit. As for valuable input: stick with your current development environment if it isn't broken and dual boot onto Windows 8 with VS2012 for the new stuff. Move away from WP7 at your earliest convenience, support for it will only decline from now on.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth thanks for undoing the downvote; at the time it was well justified and a reminder for not being lazy... I was asking because I was hoping to solely use windows 8 and vs2012 for development which isn't possible as it seems. I still hope the upcoming sdk for wp8 will provide "backwards-compatibility".

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth There will be still people using WP7, I feel a bit hurt now :(

Comment: @EaterOfCorpses Indeed, I'm still using it. And I've noticed a definite drop-off on apps being produced. Windows 7 never really had a decent critical mass for mainstream app adoption - I still frequently see people saying they support mobiles (iOS / Android), never Windows. Hopefully Windows Phone 8 will get better mass.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There we go :) --> [Windows Phone SDK 8.0](http://www.microsoft.com/de-de/download/details.aspx?id=35471)

Comment: One tiny caveat - that SDK requires Windows 8.

Comment: ... which will break your emulator if you don't have a CPU that supports the proper virtualization, since it's based on Hyper-V. Beware if you are using this on a slightly older machine.

Comment: Isn't there a way to use SDK 7.x?

Comment: You can develop WP 7/7.5 apps with the 8.0 SDK as well. Why would you like to install the 7.X SDK?

Comment: Because I dislike Windows 8 and am determined to avoid it as long as I can. Sorry.

Comment: Sorry but this doesn't make any sense. If your using Windows 7 it is only possible to use the 7.x SDK. If you're running Windows 8 you can develop WP7 apps with the 8.0 SDK.

Answer (score 1):

I have both Visual studio 2012 RTM (for Windows 8 store application development) and Windows phone 7.1.1 SDK in my Windows 8 Release Preview and they are working fine.

And like you, I am also waiting for the Windows Phone 8 SDK.(btw, there is no windows phone 7.8 sdk)

UPDATE: This [Windows Phone 8.0 SDK link](http://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us/featured/windows-phone-8-sdk) states that "you can install Windows Phone SDK 7.1 (and the WPSDK 7.1.1 Update) and continue to build apps and games that target Windows Phone 7.5. The existing Windows Phone SDK installs side by side with Visual Studio 2012, and you can feel confident that the code you write today will work on Windows Phone 8 devices."

Comment: Are you sure, I think VS2012 doesn't support WP7 app template yet.

Comment: I think what he means is, that you can install Visual Studio 2010 and 2012 side by side and it will work perfecty fine in VS2010. But as far as i know Windows Phone applications build with SDK 7.1 can't be opened with VS2012. We have to wait for the 7.8/8.0 release, which will be released later this month.

Comment: Yes, @S0me0ne that is exactly what I meant :)

Comment: @nkchandra Hey! I've went to that page prior to posting the question. It doesn't say "within" VS 2012. Rather, the side by side bit leads me to the conclusion that it doesn't work.